# Error in Insert query : syntax error at or near ","

Tags: postgresql, insert

My insert query is,

```
insert into app_library_reports  
  (app_id,adp_id,reportname,description,searchstr,command,templatename,usereporttemplate,reporttype,sentbothfiles,useprevioustime,usescheduler,cronstr,option,displaysettings,isanalyticsreport,report_columns,chart_config)
values
 (25,18,"Report_Barracuda_SpamDomain_summary","Report On Domains Sending Spam Emails","tl_tag:Barracuda_spam AND action:2","BarracudaSpam/Report_Barracuda_SpamDomain_summary.py",,,,,,,,,,,,);
```

Schema for the table 'app_library_reports' is:

```
                                                   Table "public.app_library_reports"
      Column       |  Type   |                            Modifiers                             | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                | integer | not null default nextval('app_library_reports_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 app_id            | integer |                                                                  | plain    |              |
 adp_id            | integer |                                                                  | plain    |              |
 reportname        | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 description       | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 searchstr         | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 command           | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 templatename      | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 usereporttemplate | boolean |                                                                  | plain    |              |
 reporttype        | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 sentbothfiles     | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 useprevioustime   | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 usescheduler      | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 cronstr           | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 option            | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 displaysettings   | text    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 isanalyticsreport | boolean |                                                                  | plain    |              |
 report_columns    | json    |                                                                  | extended |              |
 chart_config      | json    |                                                                  | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "app_library_reports_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "app_library_reports_adp_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (adp_id) REFERENCES app_library_adapter(id)
    "app_library_reports_app_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (app_id) REFERENCES app_library_definition(id)
```

When I execute insert query it gives error:ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","

Please help me to find out this error.Thank you.

Comment: In SQL, string constants need to be put in single quotes, not double quotes. So it should e.g. be `'Report_Barracuda_SpamDomain_summary'`. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain your immediate error is coming from the empty string of commas (i.e. `,,,,,,,`) appearing at the end of the `INSERT`.  If you don't want to specify values for a particular column, you can pass `NULL` for the value.  But in your case, since you only specify values for the first 6 columns, another way is to just specify those 6 columns names when you insert:

```
INSERT INTO app_library_reports
    (app_id, adp_id, reportname, description, searchstr, command)
VALUES
    (25, 18, 'Report_Barracuda_SpamDomain_summary',
     'Report On Domains Sending Spam Emails', 'tl_tag:Barracuda_spam AND action:2',
     'BarracudaSpam/Report_Barracuda_SpamDomain_summary.py')
```

This insert would only work if the columns *not* specified accept `NULL`.  If some of the other columns are not nullable, then you would have to pass in values for them.